# How to sort graphql array by a property that having its own resolver

Tags: graphql

Suppose I have a query that looks like this

```
{
    items {
        id
        name
        price
    }
}
```

- items resolver is returning an array.
- `price` is having its own resolver

How can I say, apply a sorting logic on items array based on price? after all the prices are resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. Your `items` field must resolve before the `price` field does, since the value of each Item must be made available to the `price` resolver.

The only way to get around this is to move the logic inside your `price` resolver into the items resolver itself. A simple example:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    items: async () {
      const items = await getItems()
      return Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => {
        const price = await getPriceForItem(item)
        return { ...item, price }
      }))
    }
  }
}
```